# Force https on Wordpress multisite

Tags: wordpress, ssl, https

I've got a Wordpress multisite and I'm trying to force https programmatically (better than via .htaccess as htaccess has many rules, set from cache plugin and the multisite itself).

The code I'm using is this one:

```
if ( FORCE_HTTPS && (!isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) || strtolower($_SERVER['HTTPS']) != 'on' ))
{
    //echo("Location: " . "https://" . $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
    header("Location: " . "https://" . $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
    exit();
}
```

It's working properly in main site but not in subdmoains, but curiously is I type https://subsite.domain.com it works properly, but if I go with this redirection I see a blank page.

The certificate is working properly and as I sayed, if I type the full adress I see everything ok

What's going wrong or how can I force https?

Thank you

Comment: What does the PHP log file say?

Comment: Actually, it doesn't seem to be logging "all" errors although log should be active and shows only some errors

Comment: No, if I comment these lines everything works fine

Comment: Well, I see these entries in the log, ModSecurity: Audit log: Failed to unlock global mutex: Permission denied [hostname "sub.domain.com"] [uri "/index.php"] [unique_id "T154oFJimH0AAF3y1WEAAAAG"]

Comment: Can you turn on PHP errors (error_reporting(E_ALL);) and try to trigger an error by creating a parse error please?

Comment: Then that's why it's blank. If you find that error, it'll be fixed.

Comment: I don't think so, this error entry appears long back in time and my https tests started no more than 1.5 hours ago

Answer (score 1):

1. validate your server ssl for errors:
   http://www.digicert.com/help/
2. use this wp plugin:
   http://wordpress.org/plugins/force-ssl-everywhere/
   ssl on logged in